# Why doesn't my terminal shows me irb(main):001:0> when I enter irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm a complete newbie in this field and I am currently "trying" to study Python and Ruby.

I did everything what the tutorial said, but my terminal just won't show me the `irb(main):001:0>` thing to proceed. I'm not sure if it is because the tutorial is like 4 years old, but the same 4 year old Python tutorial's method is working just fine, but Ruby is just making me feel dumb in like 5 minutes after I started.. I would really appreciate some help.

```
iseongmin-ui-MacBook-Pro:~ sm.lee$ irb
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    2: from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/irb:23:in '<main>'  
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0  /rubygems.rb:302:in 'activate_bin_path'  
            /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in 'find_spec_for_exe':  
can't find gem irb (>= 0.a) with executable irb (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Comment: This error is caused by installing Ruby via Homebrew. I recommend using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) instead – it's a Ruby version manager which allows you to install multiple Ruby versions. Never had any issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ruby 2.6.0 installation no more ships irb. 
You should install it with `rubygems`.

`gem list | grep irb` should output something like `irb 1.0.0`. If not, run `gem install irb`.

Its also possible that the `bin` directory for gems is not in your path, is typically add somethling like this to my `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, etc.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')"
```

Comment: irb is not a gem it's build-in ruby repl.

Comment: @Зелёный Wasn't sure on mac. It does not come included on Arch, have to install it additionally. Irregardless the path issue should solve the issue, so not sure why the downvote. https://github.com/ruby/irb

Comment: oh, since ruby 2.6.0 installation no more ships `irb`.

Comment: Yeah, was surprised at first time I tried to run it with clean install. Thought perhaps it was just my distro, but apparently it is a new thing not to include.

Comment: IRB is a _default gem_ in Ruby 2.6. If you have to install it manually, something is wrong.

Comment: I can't speak for all distro, but It most definitely is **not** a *default* gem on Arch Linux. Just confirmed it with new Ruby install.

Comment: Thank you so much ForeverZer0, it worked!! Now I can finally start my tutorial now :)

Comment: @ForeverZer0 FYI the removal of IRB from Arch's Ruby 2.6 package seems to be a bug, see [FS#62709](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/62709?project=5&order=dateopened&sort=desc)

Comment: @Stefan Ah, I see thanks for the info. Was curious why it would get removed, so double-checked to make I wasn't mistaken, and it was indeed excluded. That would explain it.

Comment: What a coincidence that both, Homebrew and Arch screwed up IRB.